# Not able to open the child window on same running cypress script. Child window link is dynamic

Tags: javascript, cypress

my cypress code snippet:

```
    cy.visit("http://localhost:8080");   
    cy.get("#EmailId").type("admin@abc.com");
    cy.get("#PasswordId").type("admin@123");
    cy.get("#LoginButton > .v-btn__content").click();
    cy.get("#OpenFilterButton").click();  //this is for filter icon to open the child window.
```

```
       cy.wait(3000);
       cy.server();
       cy.route('**/investigation`enter code here`/*/popupwindow/*/searchinstancefilter');
       const investigationNum = '2925223647'  
       const searchInstanceNum = '2358303736'
       const filterscreenpath=     
      "/investigation/${investigationNum}/popupwindow/${searchInstanceNum}/searchinstancefilter";
```

Below is the HTML Code of that child window(Project is developed to run in Electron browser):

```
<template>
  <v-btn color="secondary" icon v-on:click="ListActionClick()">
    <v-icon class="List-Button-Icon">mdi-filter</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "sample",
  data() {
    return {
      authToken: "",
      refreshToken: "",
      path: "http://localhost:8080/#/childwindow"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ListActionClick: function() {
      let WindowSize = { width: 0, height: 0 };
      WindowSize.width = 700;
      WindowSize.height = 600;
      let WindowURL = `LaunchWindow?token=${this.authToken}&refreshToken=${this.refreshToken}&rememberMe=false&path=${this.path}`;
      const ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
      ipcRenderer.send("asynchronous-OpenWindow", {
        WindowURL,
        WindowSize
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have tried this also but did not worked anything.
Application is build to run on only Electron browser.

Below find the attachment of my issue:
[image: child window issue explanation]

Comment: Please share the HTML of the filter button. And what happens currently when you click it, do you get any errors or it just simply doesn't open with no errors.

Comment: Hi,
@AlapanDas.. I have added the html code in my question. Please check and help me, my Cypress Automation testing is got stuck due this problem. This project is build in Electron based and runs properly in electron browser, there child window also gets opened properly.